# What is wrong in maclaurin series arccos calculations using java?

Tags: java, trigonometry, taylor-series

I am using mclaurins series to calculate arccos(x^2-1) but when i compare it to a result of math.acos it differs.
Here is my code:

```
    public class Maclaurin {

    public static int factorial(int fact) {
        if(fact==0)
            return 1;
        return fact*factorial(fact-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, j;
    double function = 0, x,result;

    x=0;

        for (int n = 0; n < 8; n++) {

            function=((factorial(2*n))/(Math.pow(4, n)*Math.pow(factorial(n),2)*(2*n+1)))*Math.pow((Math.pow(x, 2)-1),2*n+1);
            result=(Math.PI/2)-function;

            System.out.println("x= "+x+" y= "+result);
            System.out.println("Test "+Math.acos(Math.pow(x, 2)-1));
            x+=0.13;
        }




    }


    }

Programm output. test is a value calculated with Math.arccos and it differs from y calculated with mclaurins formula:

    x= 0.0 y= 2.5707963267948966
    Test 3.141592653589793
    x= 0.13 y= 1.7291549939933966
    Test 2.9574849820283498
    x= 0.26 y= 1.6236496851024964
    Test 2.771793621843802
    x= 0.39 y= 1.5848621264898726
    Test 2.5828078861333155
    x= 0.52 y= 1.5725761587226181
    Test 2.3885331918392687
    x= 0.65 y= 1.5708496332463704
    Test 2.1864594293995867
    x= 0.78 y= 1.570796415168701
    Test 1.9731661516473589
    x= 0.91 y= 1.5707963267948972
    Test 1.7435543826662978
```

EDIT:New code where calculations are in maclaurin function and i call it from main function. works good for all values except first 3:
    package maclaurin;

```
public class Maclaurin {
    private static double x;

//public static int factorial(int fact) {
//    if(fact==0)
//        return 1;
//    return fact*factorial(fact-1);
//}
   public static double factorial(int fact) {
    if(fact==0)
        return 1;
    return fact*factorial(fact-1);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         x = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
            {
                maclaurin(x);
                x=x+0.14;
            }

    }

public static void maclaurin(double value){
    double function = 0, x, result;

    x =value;

    for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++) {
        function += ((factorial(2 * n)) / (Math.pow(4, n) * Math.pow(factorial(n), 2) * (2 * n + 1)))
                * Math.pow((Math.pow(x, 2) - 1), 2 * n + 1);
    }

    result = (Math.PI / 2) - function;
    System.out.println("x= " + x + " y= " + result);
    System.out.println("Test " + Math.acos(Math.pow(x, 2) - 1));
}




}
```

Comment: Does it differ? I can see no difference. Perhaps if we could *see* the difference you're talking about, we might be better able to help?

Comment: @Andreas here is the programm output added

Comment: @Andreas i checked formula several times and didnt find errors

Comment: @ГринюкАндрей did you compare your series expansion to e.g. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maclaurin+series+arccos(x%5E2-1))?

Answer (score 2):

The factorial of 16, which appears in your loop, is greater than `MAX_INT`.

I get:

```
 >> factorial(16)
 2.0923e+013
 >> 2^31
 2.1475e+009
```

in Octave.  You need to do an analytic simplification to keep that in range or use `double` instead of `int` there.

Comment: although it is an issue, it doesn't answer the question. He has wrong values for small input as well

Comment: @Brick i ll check this but as JohnnyAW already said it doesnt work even for small values

Comment: I didn't check how far how this series is good since you have the obvious coding error with the size of the integer. I agree with @JohnnyAW, though, that you cannot expect the series to converge to the right answer unless you're "close enough" to the point where you did the expansion. How far you can go depends on the nature of the function, how many terms you kept, and accuracy needed. If you don't understand that part, I suggest reading about Maclauren series elsewhere or asking some questions a the math SE.  Also, if you want very large factorials, consider using Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't understand, what maclaurin series (taylor's series) is actually do. It can calculate an approximate value. You will get the exact value only for n -> ∞. Since we can't calculate that, we need to define some n and stop our calculation there. You have to add every single part of the summ to get the actual value. So basically you should iterate over n and ADD the calculated value to `function` and after the loop you can calculate `result`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    double x = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i < 8;i++){
        System.out.println("x: " + x + " maclaurin: " + maclaurin(x));
        System.out.println("Test: " + Math.acos(Math.pow(x, 2) - 1));

        x += 0.14;
    }
}

public static double maclaurin(double x){
    double function = 0;

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        function += ((factorial(2 * n)) / (Math.pow(4, n) * Math.pow(factorial(n), 2) * (2 * n + 1)))
                * Math.pow((Math.pow(x, 2) - 1), 2 * n + 1);
    }

    return (Math.PI / 2) - function;
}
```

this way I got pretty close values:

```
x: 0.0 maclaurin: 2.962490972738185
Test: 3.141592653589793
x: 0.14 maclaurin: 2.8972172328920296
Test: 2.9432779368601296
x: 0.28 maclaurin: 2.7366715068800485
Test: 2.7429790581451043
x: 0.42000000000000004 maclaurin: 2.5381695201901326
Test: 2.5385256934250617
x: 0.56 maclaurin: 2.3273181153351756
Test: 2.327323409412957
x: 0.7000000000000001 maclaurin: 2.105981109221438
Test: 2.1059811170704963
x: 0.8400000000000001 maclaurin: 1.8696239609917407
Test: 1.8696239609918046
x: 0.9800000000000001 maclaurin: 1.6104066839613247
Test: 1.6104066839613247
```

it seems, that result is not as good for x close to 0. You can increase `n` to get better results, but at some point you will get `NaN`, since `factorial` will overflow at some point.

don't forget to change `factorial` like @Brick suggested:

```
public static double factorial(int fact) {
    if(fact==0)
        return 1;
    return fact*factorial(fact-1);
}
```

if you wonder how to calculate `factorial` in an iterative way, here is an example(it actually doesn't matter in this particular case, but hey, we are here to learn new things, right?):

```
public static double factorial(int fact) {
    double result = 1;
    while(fact > 1){
        result *= fact--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

EDIT: changed `fact` parameter to `int`

EDIT2: wrapped `maclaurin` function and added more values

EDIT3: added iterative `factorial`

Comment: You probably should change the parameter to `factorial()` back to an `int`, but keep the return value as a `double`.

Comment: @Andreas yeah, `fact==0` would be otherwise little "dirty" :)

Comment: I know you're keeping with the question, but `factorial()` should be a loop, not a recursion. You probably won't call it with values high enough to be a problem, but recursion may cause `StackOverflowError`. Besides, looping is faster than recursion.

Comment: @JohnnyAW tried to make it as a loop but it works not as good as ur example. I moved ur code to a function and i am calling it in a loop. here is my code: `public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         x = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
            {
                maclaurin(x);
                x=x+0.14;
            }

    }`

Comment: can you add your new code in the question and show `maclaurin`?

Comment: @ГринюкАндрей I just tested your code and it worked. I noticed, that it works for values close to 0 not as good as for other values. You can experiment with `n`. If you set `n` higher, you will get better results, since you compute more terms and "getting closer" to ∞

Comment: Just to be complete, even if you could take n -> infinity, some functions have series that diverge outside some distance from the expansion point. Not sure if this function is one of them or not and not motivated to check it.  Look for "radius of convergence."